# topology-components of a space

Tags: general-topology

can anybody please explain me what is meant by "the components" of space?

How can we determine the components of a space?

What are the components of a cofinite space and  cocountable space?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(topology)

Comment: Path connected components? Connected components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a space. A subset $C$ of $X$ is a *connected component* of $X$ if (1) $C$ is connected, and (2) whenever $C\subsetneqq Y\subseteq X$, the set $Y$ is **not** connected. In other words, $C$ is a *maximal* connected subset of $X$.

Define a relation $\sim$ on $X$ by saying that $x\sim y$ if and only if there is a connected set $C\subseteq X$ that contains both $x$ and $y$. It’s not too hard to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and that the $\sim$-equivalence classes are the connected components of $X$. This implies that the connected components of a space form a partition of the space into maximal connected subsets. And since the closure of a connected set is connected, each of these maximal connected subsets (i.e., components) of $X$ must be closed.

If $X$ has the cofinite topology, every infinite subset of $X$ is connected. Assuming that $X\ne\varnothing$, there are two possibilities.

1. If $X$ is finite, its components are its singletons, i.e., its one-point subsets.
2. If $X$ is infinite, $X$ is connected, so its only component is $X$ itself.

If $X$ has the co-countable topology, every uncountable subset of $X$ is connected, and there are again two possibilities.

1. If $X$ is countable, its components are its singletons, i.e., its one-point subsets.
2. If $X$ is uncountable, $X$ is connected, so its only component is $X$ itself.

Comment: thank you very much Brian!I understood it clearly!thanks once again:)

Comment: @ccc: You’re very welcome.

Comment: @ Brian,is it possible for me to contact you through e-mails?

Comment: Try `b.scott at csuohio dot edu`; it’s widely visible on the web, so I don’t mind posting it, and it still forwards to my real address. It has a fairly aggressive spam trap, so put MSE at the beginning of the subject; that way I’ll notice it even if it goes into the spam trap.

Comment: thanks Brian!I will contact you as soon as possible.

Comment: @ sir Brian,did you get my e-mail?

Comment: @ccc: I did, and I’m typing up some of the answers right now.